# megaraid: Logical Drives at different RAID levels

Tags: raid, lsi, megaraid

I am currently using a SuperMicro machine that has an on-board LSI 2208 controller (MegaRAID class).

I want to create a single array from two drives and then carve that up into:

- one RAID1 100GB logical drive
- one RAID0 logical drive taking up the rest of the array

Can I do this with the LSI2208?

If not, is there a different LSI controller that supports this?

Comment: From a quick skim of [the manual](http://www.lsi.com/downloads/Public/MegaRAID%20Common%20Files/SASUG_51530-00_RevG.pdf) I did not see how to do this. So have an upvote and I wish you good luck.

Comment: Contact LSI would be my suggestion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By partitions, do you mean that you want to create a single RAID array and then create more than one logical drive on that array?

```
# Clear the RAID config
megacli cfgclr -a0

# Create a RAID10 array from 4 drives with two logical drives,
# one 100GB and one comprised of the rest of the space
megacli cfgldadd -r1 "[?:0,?:1,?:2,?:3]" WB ADRA NoCachedBadBBU -sz100000 -sz0 -a0
```

Unfortunately, all logical drives created from a single array must be at the same RAID level.

I would suggest putting the disks into JBOD mode and doing the RAID in software:

```
megacli pdmakejbod -physdrv "[?:0,?:1]" -a0
```

Comment: Kind of.  Let me try to translate into LSI-speak.  Let's say I have two physical drives: Drive0 and Drive1.  I want to take 100GB of Drive0 and 100GB of Drive1 and mirror it (RAID1).  I then want to take the remainder of Drive0 and create a second logical drive with the remainder of the space.  Finally I want to take the remainder of Drive1 and create a third logical drive with the rest of it's space.  In the end I would have a RAID1 for my OS, and two RAID0s.  Make sense?

Comment: I edited your question to better word what you are trying to accomplish. Please feel free to modify it if it doesn't actually reflect what you're doing.

Comment: Thanks for the input everyone.  I've sent an email to LSI just to see what they say.  We will most likely go with the software raid suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

RAID arrays are made up of physical drives, not partitions. Once you have added the disks to a RAID array you can then create multiple [logical or virtual disks](http://artipc10.vub.ac.be/wordpress/2011/09/12/megacli-useful-commands/) on the array using megacli. Those virtual disks can then be partitioned using FDISK or various other file system utilities as if they were physical drives.

Comment: You can do this on HP SmartArray controllers to be fair, mad I know but you can, can't think of a great reason to do it but there you go - no idea about megaraid however.

Comment: @Chopper3 You have any documentation on that? A quick search for `HP SmartArray raid partitions` didn't show anything that talked about using Partitions to create a RAID array. I also looked through the HP Array Configuration Utility on one of our servers and didn't see it in there either.